# Org is implemented on top of Outline mode

Tags: org-mode, outline

Org manual states in its beginning

> Org is implemented on top of Outline mode, which makes it possible to
>   keep the content of large files well structured.

I referenced 'outline-mode' by C-h f outline-mode, and curious about :

Is outline-mode is part of org, which was written by org team?
or it a emacs-builtin before Org?

How could I check it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option is to check the source.

`M-x find-library outline`

You'll find in the header comments:

> ;; Copyright (C) 1986, 1993-1995, 1997, 2000-2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>
> ;; This file is part of GNU Emacs.

`M-x find-library org`

> ;; Copyright (C) 2004-2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>
> ;; This file is part of GNU Emacs.

So, both are included with Emacs but outline-mode predates org-mode.

Poking further you can see that org-mode is actually implemented as a [derived mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Derived-Modes.html) of outline:

> (define-derived-mode org-mode outline-mode "Org" ...

Comment: Another important point: outline is a single file with ~1000 lines of code. org is > 150000 lines of code in 200 files. So org started as an extension of outline, but the outline part is a very small piece of the whole system.